# IRandomAccessStreamReference to StorageFile Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10

I was able to cast IRandomAccessStreamReference to StorageFile by just a simple casting in **Windows 8.1**.

**In Windows 10** it throws

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference' to type 'Windows.Storage.StorageFile'

Any suggestion on how I can work around this?

Comment: How did you obtain this `IRandomAccessFile`?

Comment: Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact.Thumbnail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you still need a `StorageFile` object, you could use the `CreateStreamedFileAsync` method to wrap the returned stream into a temporary file (avoids writing it all out once then reading it all back in again).

Answer (score 3):

StorageFile implements IRandomAccessStreamReference; it isn't necessarily possible to safely cast from the latter to the former without checking your instance implements it and handling the case where it does not.

It's probably the case that you were using a method that was declared to return IRandomAccessStreamReference but coincidentally returned StorageFile given certain inputs on Windows 8, although this was not part of the API contract.

If you really need it to be a file, can't you write it to a temporary file?

Comment: That's a valid point. They have changed what was behind Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact.Thumbnail. Maybe I should rethink my logic.